# Bounding $\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2^k}}$

Tags: summation, asymptotics, estimation

I'm looking for a bound depending on $N$ of $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2^k}}$.

The following holds $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2^k}} = \sum_{k=1}^N \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{ki}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{\substack{q\geq 0 \\ 1\leq p \leq N\\pq=n}}\frac{1}{2^{pq}}\leq 2N$ which does not seem accurate.

Numerical trials suggest that $\displaystyle N-\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2^k}}$ is a convergent sequence (it's easy to prove it is decreasing).

Comment: Is that written correctly? For $N = 1$ you have $2 < 1$.

Comment: @muaddib I've made some edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$\sum_{k\leq N}\frac{2^{k}}{2^{k}-1}=N+\sum_{k\leq N}\frac{1}{2^{k}-1}
 $$ and [recalling](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html) that holds the identity $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-a^{k}}=\frac{\psi_{\frac{1}{a}}\left(1\right)+\log\left(a-1\right)+\log\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)}{\log\left(a\right)}
 $$ where $\psi_{q}\left(z\right)
 $ is the $q
 $-polygamma function, we have $$\sum_{k\leq N}\frac{2^{k}}{2^{k}-1}=N+\sum_{k\leq N}\frac{1}{2^{k}-1}\leq N+\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{1}{2^{k}-1}=$$ 
 $$=N+1-\frac{\psi_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(1\right)}{\log\left(2\right)}\approx N+1.606695.
 $$

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2^k}} = 1+ \frac{1}{2^k-1}$$
so
$$N \le \sum_{k=1}^N\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2^k}} \le N+ \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{2^k-1} \le N+2$$
since $1\le \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{2^k-1} \le 2$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2^k}}=\sum_{k=1}^{N}\left(1+\sum_{j\geq 1}\frac{1}{2^{kj}}\right)\leq N+1+\frac{1}{3}+\ldots+\frac{1}{2^N-1}\leq N+\frac{5}{3}.$$